# The sockettimeoutexception is frustrating on Google App engine(JAVA). Workaround needed

Tags: google-app-engine

I am connecting to a 3rd party server on the following wsdl 
http://webservices.ticketvala.com/axis2/services/WSTicketvala?wsdl

I am using JAX-WS to generate client code and call relevent method on 3rd party server. 3rd party server may take time between 15-25 seconds to send response.
It works fine on tomcat.

Now when i deploy this to GAE 1.5.3, often i get ScocketTimeoutException in less than 10 seconds. Sometimes it is succesfull taking even 20 seconds. I want to know why it fails many times. And any workaround to increase this response deadline time / to avoid this ScoketTimeOutException forever.

Similarly,

I have another RESTfull service at http://ticketgoose.com/bookbustickets/TGWSStationNameResponseAction.do?" +
"event=getStationDetails&password=123456&userId=ctshubws

I am connecting it through java.net.URL and many times i get TimeoutException. How can i raise this timeout limit to more than 30 seconds?

Thanks
Deepak

Answer (score 0):

No user-initiated request can take more than 30 seconds to complete in Google App Engine:
http://code.google.com/intl/en/appengine/docs/java/runtime.html#The_Request_Timer

And a HTTP request to a external URL in a user-initiated request can't take more than 10 seconds to complete:
http://code.google.com/intl/en/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/overview.html#Requests

If you need to do the overall work in more than 30 seconds and can do it in background (not needing to return the response directly via HTTP), use [Task Queues](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/). Note that the simplest way to do background work with tasks is to use the [DeferredTask](http://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/overview-push.html#Deferred_Tasks). And the best part: HTTP requests to external URLs on tasks can take up to [10 minutes to complete](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/browse_thread/thread/95f7d9fae2a54e14).